# Cost of looking up a tuple in a list of tuple?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of tuples of the form `list = [(key1,value1), (key2,value2)]`, then is it fast/good to look up if a tuple exists in the list like this: `(key_x,value_x) in list` ? Also how does python search the list?! Does it compare pointers or how?! I'm new to Python coming from Java.

Answer (score 2):

`item in your_list` is `O(n)` operation in Python. If all items are distinct and the order doesn't matter and you need to do multiple looks up then you could use a `set()` instead of a list. `item in your_set` is `O(1)` (`O(n)` worst case).

Comment: where can I find those information about the cost? In Java one would consult the javadocs but I'm not able to find these info for python!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what the contents of the list are. Lookup in a list is `O(n)`. Every item starting from the first will be compared to whatever you are looking for until it is found.

```
item in l # l is a list
```

is equivalent to

```
for i in l:
    if i == item:
        return True
return False
```